# Array of Input Fields only sending First Input Value

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a pair of input fields (Link title, link report) that can be duplicated by the user to include multiple links to the record created when the form is submitted, but I noticed that despite the fields being appended with an array counter for the name e.g. `reportLink[2]` the additional link fields are not being included in the body on the form submission and I was wondering if this would be related to my front-end code or if this process is the result of the back-end code configuration. At the moment, all that is collected in the body is the pair of fields.

Here are my fields:

```
<div class="form-group report-link-container p-2">
    <label for="report-link">Link to Reports</label>
    <p><i>Please make sure all visible URL fields contain http:// or https://. Otherwise you will receive an error</i></p>
    <div class="annotation__footer-report-link-form-container">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary setup-add-field mb-2">+ Add Another Report</a>
        <br/>
        <label for="report-title">Title</label>
        <a href="#" class="setup-add-field">Add Another Report</a>
        <div class="annotation__footer-report-link-form-container">
        <input type="text" name="reportTitle[0]" class="form-control annotation-report-title" value=""placeholder="Title">
        <input type="text" name="reportLink[0]" class="form-control annotation-report-link" value="" placeholder="Link">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery for appending additional fields and name counter:

```
//Append or remove form fields for report links
    var formField = $('.report-link-container');
    var i = $('.report-link-container p').size();
    var fieldName = $('input.annotation-report-link')[0].name.replace('[0]', '');
    var reportTitle = $('input.annotation-report-title')[0].name.replace('[0]', '');
    var reportTitlePlaceholder = $('input.annotation-report-title')[0].placeholder; 
    var fieldPlaceholder = $('input.annotation-report-title')[0].placeholder;
    var reportTitleCounter = 1;
    var fieldCounter = 1;
    $('.setup-add-field').on('click', function() {
        $('<div class="annotation__footer-report-link-form-container"><div class="report-link-container"><p class="setup-form-field-wrapper"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a><label>Title</label><input type="text" class="form-control annotation-report-title" size="20" name="' + reportTitle + '['+ reportTitleCounter++ +']" value=""' + reportTitlePlaceholder + '" placeholder="Title"/><label>Link</label><input type="text" class="form-control annotation-report-link" size="20" name="' + fieldName + '['+ fieldCounter++ +']" value=""' + fieldPlaceholder + '" placeholder="Link"/></p></div></div>').appendTo(formField);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('.report-link-container').on('click', '.remove', function() {
      if (i >= 1) {
        $(this).closest('.annotation__footer-report-link-form-container').remove();
        i--;
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Resulting body regardless if additional fields are appended and present on form submission:

`reportTitle[0]`
`reportLink[0]`

Comment: Where is `.report-link-container` ? It's referenced as `formField` but doesn't exist in DOM initially... yet `formField` is what the dynamic HTML `appendsTo()` ...?

Comment: replace reportTitle[0] with reportTitle[] and reportLink[0] with reportLink[].

Comment: @zer00ne sorry about that. I accidentally left out that div from this question, but edited and added it

Comment: @SangitaKendre if I do that, then the additional form fields from my jQuery have names like `reportTitle[][1]`